# asp.net required field validation called on every button action

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a simple asp.net code with the asp.net required validator control, the problem is that I only have one submit button called GO, and a dropdownlist that looks for the selection :
clear, submit, cancel.

No matter what option is selected, the required field validation is being fired.

Is there a way to code the page so only when the selected value is Submit it validates?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName" controltovalidate="txtName" errormessage="Please enter your name!" />
    <br /><br />


    <asp:DropDownList ID="dpAction" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem>Submit</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Reset">Reset</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>Cancel</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;
             <asp:Button ID="btnAction" runat="server" onclick="btnAction_Click" Text="Go" 
                 Width="40px" />
```

Comment: can you post the logic of your btnAction_Click?

Comment: it just checks for the value if is == submit then it will process some values and send to email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to use a custom validator, and you would need to write the client side code for it also if you want client side validation.

I'm assuming you have a text box or something else that is required when "dpAction" is set to "Submit"?

So for example you would do something like this in your markup

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
   OnServerValidate="TextValidate" 
   ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
   ErrorMessage="Text must be specified if Submit is selected">
```

and in your code-behind

```
protected void TextValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
   args.IsValid = dpAction.SelectedValue == "Submit" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Right I have several textboxes which are validated by the asp.net required field validator. I did not write any javascript, just used the one in asp.net. But the thing is that is fired once the button is clicked, and I dont want to validate for example the option selected is clear

Comment: Can this custom validor use with the validation summary to show the required fields?

Comment: Yes.You may need to set the error message in the TextValidate method if you want to show different messages depending on the context

Comment: Whatever is defined in the error message will show up in the summary assuming you have hooked them up correctly

Comment: So if I have 20 controls to validate do I need to write a method for each one?

Comment: In short yes, the better approach would be to subclass one of the validator classes and make it suit your purposes in a more general way such that you would just have to include 20 validators on the page and not 20 validation methods as well

Answer (score 0):

using "required" attribute.
its new in html 5

Answer (score 0):

you should set ValidationGroup for each Validator!
for all controls that you want to be validated and the button to fire the validation:

and the button must have same validaton group with your validator!